# File listing and empty result with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I try to monitor a repertory list and their sub-repertory with a QFileSystemWatcher. It works fine but when I catch the signal directoryChanged, the new file added in the repertory pointed by the path is not known.
To know the new file, when the program is started, I list the files with a QDirIterator and I store the result in a QStringList :

```
dirIt = new QDirIterator(ui->lineRepProjets->text(), QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
fileList = new QStringList();
while (dirIt->hasNext())
{
    qDebug() << "FILE : " << dirIt->fileName();
    *fileList << dirIt->next();
}
delete dirIt;
```

After, when I catch the signal, I make an other list of the repertory and I compare.

The problem is the result isn't correct ! As you can see I print the fileName of each found file in qDebug.
I have this result :

FILE :  ""
FILE :  "Bonjour.txt"
FILE :  "Hello.txt"

Whereas in one of my repertory I have 3 files : "Bonjour.txt", "Hello.txt" AND "Test.txt"

So in my QStringList I have an empty string and I havn't the file "Test.txt" and i don't understand where is my mistake.

Thank you for your help !

EDIT :

I solved my problem with your help, thank you !! The final code is :

```
QDirIterator fileIt(ui->lineRepProjets->text(), QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
fileList = new QStringList();
do
{
    *fileList << fileIt.next();
} while (fileIt.hasNext());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you keep adding next filename to the list. At one point, your iterator points to the element behind the last element, hence the empty string.

I would change the loop to this :

```
do
{
    qDebug() << "FILE : " << dirIt->fileName();
    *fileList << dirIt->fileName();
    dirIt->next();
}
while (dirIt->hasNext());
```

Comment: Your solution is could be better but it don't work because dirIt->fileName(); contains an empty string at begining and I don't understand why !!!! And it's a real problem for me ..... To get the first fileName I have to write dirIt->next; qDebug() << dirIt->fileName(); !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the last file name because the last file has no next file.
`dirIt->hasNext()` return false for the last file

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html#hasNext

Maybe it is ugly but you can use this code:

```
while (dirIt->hasNext())
{
    qDebug() << "FILE : " << dirIt->fileName();
    *fileList << dirIt->next();
}

qDebug() << "FILE : " << dirIt->fileName();
*fileList << dirIt->next();
```

Comment: Oh yes it's true ..... So how I am supposed to get back the name of the last file? And How I can prevent the addition of empty string?

Comment: I try to write this : while (dirIt->fileName() != "") but the problem is I have a empty string in first ....

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to call next immediately. This should work:

```
QString thePath("./");
QDirIterator it(thePath, QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
QStringList fileList;
while (it.hasNext())
    fileList.append(it.next());
```